# Compute the area of the union of the intersections of two conditions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, conditional

I have four conditions over the two-dimensional domain $x,y\in[a,b]$. I want to use `NIntegrate` to compute the area of the union of the intersection of the two conditions con1 and con2 with the intersection of the two conditions con3 and con4, i.e. the region $(con1 \cap con2)\cup(con3 \cap con4)$. Does the following code give me the correct answer?

```
NIntegrate[
  Boole[{con1 && con2}, {con3 && con4}], 
  {x, a, b}, {y, a, b}
]
```

Comment: I'm confused.... Why can't you tell if it gives you the correct answer?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Corrected :)

Comment: I *still* am confused.  Why don't you simply try your code on an example and see if it gives the correct answer??  Be explicit about the conditions... that's all.  I don't see how we can help you if you don't try your code.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Since I do not know the area of my desired condition analytically, they can be computed only numerically, and `NIntegrate` was the only way I knew! If it is so clear, why cannot you answer if this code is correct in general (for any conditions and not only for an example) or not? My question is for a general situation not only for a particular example!

Comment: It is ***NOT*** so clear, and I never said that.  Your accepted "answer" from CraigCarter shows a single example (the kind you could have and should have done on your own), but doesn't answer the full general problem.  Are you now *positive* that CraigCarter's solution will work for every case you have in mind?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "the kind you could have and should have done on your own"; if I knew the way/code that CraigCarter has used in his answer, then, I would not ask my question :) Please assume that some people in this forum (like me) are beginners in Mathematica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could compare it in this fashion:

```
ir1 = ImplicitRegion[
  x + y < 1 && x - y <  1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}]

ir2 = ImplicitRegion[
  x + y > 0 && x - y >  0, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}]

RegionPlot[RegionUnion[ir1, ir2]]

Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] RegionUnion[ir1, ir2] ]
```

or

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] RegionUnion[ir1, ir2] ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, I see that my ode is fundamentally wrong; this part `Boole[{con1 && con2}, {con3 && con4}]` becomes red when I try to run it. So, my desired area can be computed in the way you mentioned. May I ask you to explain what $1$ stands in your `Integrate` or `NIntegrate` code? Sorry if it is a primary question; I am a beginner in Mathematica.

Comment: And if my conditions are very complicated, and if it is needed to increase the precision of the result, where I should add `PlotPoints`, ` Precision` ,  or `MaxRecursion` in your code?

Comment: `{x, y} \[Element] RegionUnion[ir1, ir2]` is analogous to the region you want.  It is equivalent to "dA" for a two dimensional integral.  So, integrating 1 over dA gives you the area you want.  I left the `NIntegrate` as an option. If your region is a meshed region, you will need to do a numerical approximation.  HTH.